# Agregar o eliminar información sin actualizar pagina

Tags: java

Tengo una duda y no se que debo usar para lo siguiente.
Estoy realizando un aplicativo web en java de compartir información con otros usuarios mi pregunta es como puedo hacer que cuando yo elimine algo se le elimine a la otra persona sin necesidad de que la otra persona refresque la pagina para que esa información desaparezca o si agrego algo a esa persona le llegue esa información sin refrescar la pagina.

Si me pueden regalar la información de como se llama lo que debo usar para eso.

Comment: Lo que planteas es algo similar a un chat? Mostrando cambios en tiempo real según los usuarios escriben/borran? En ese caso, deberías usar sockets. Si no, lo mejor sería usar ajax (fetch api de javascript, por ejemplo) para recoger los cambios cada X segundos.

Comment: Si exacto como un chat mostrando cambios en tiempo real.
Vale lo revisare.
Gracias por tu respuesta @Benito-B